# React App does not launch and gives error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I tried creating a react app from this and I was able to create all the files and folders from the steps they have mentioned for setting up the environment. But while running the `npm start` command, it gives the following error:

```
C:\Users\name\myfirstreact>npm start
$ react-scripts start

There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.1"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack-dev-server was detected higher up in the tree:

  C:\Users\name\node_modules\webpack-dev-server (version: 3.11.2)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "webpack-dev-server" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if C:\Users\name\node_modules\webpack-dev-server is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls webpack-dev-server in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack-dev-server.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Please help me with this and this might be very silly question, but I have just started learning it, so basically I'm a noob at this.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the suggested fixing steps?

Comment: @AzizaKasenova Yes, I tried that, but what falconFlight tried to tell was unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the mentioned steps in the message? Did you try deleting the `package-lock.json`? Or deleting node_modules and running `npm install`?

Comment: yes, I followed all that was given by the prompt.
didn't work out.

Comment: As per Jose Javier Sanahuja answer try adding -g flag with your command and give it a shot, also make sure that you chnage your start script to `"start:dev": "webpack-dev-server"`, then you can simply `run npm run start:dev`

Comment: Could you please explain this?

Comment: Ok, so what I wanted to say is that the server gives you an error related to `"webpack-dev-server": "3.11.1"` server. Did you try adding that package globally so that you don't to give another command for it to launch?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It still gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you installed that dependency globaly? I mean webpack-dev-server 3.11.2?

Check it and remove it or replace it for a previous one

Try this command on the console. This is just a hunch. It May not solve your problem

npm uninstall -g webpack-dev-server

Comment: How do I do that?
please don't mind. But I'm really new to this.

Comment: Have 2 or 3 difference projects to work. If you get stock in one, change to the other. You should love this error because in a matter of days, you'll learn something New to avoid these error. Try npm uninstall -g webpack-dev-server